# Do you need to import the "in" class when using IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, error-handling

I'm just starting to learn java and came across this project where we use IntelliJ to debug an exercise. In the console I ran into the error :
"java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   class In
location: class DebugExercise3
"
I highlighted the red font in the IntelliJ as **\Bold**\ here. Could someone help me understand why?

```
 public class DebugExercise3 {
    public static int countTurnips(**In** in) {
        int totalTurnips = 0;
        while (!in.**isEmpty()**) {
            String vendor = in.**readString**();
            String foodType = in.**readString**();
            double cost = in.**readDouble**();
            int numAvailable = in.**readInt**();
            if (foodType.equals("turnip")) {
                int newTotal = totalTurnips + numAvailable;
                totalTurnips = newTotal;
            }
            in.**readLine**();
        }
        return totalTurnips;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        **In** in = new **In**("foods.csv");
        System.out.println(countTurnips(in));
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to import it?

Comment: Yes.  `In` is not a built-in Java class.  (It sounds like it comes from whatever course you're using to learn Java; it's not part of Java itself.)

Comment: if the `In` class is not in the same package as the class where it is used, and not a class from `java.lang`, then you must import it

Comment: @LouisWasserman Thank you. That's exactly why...Didn't realize that!  Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

If the class "In" is not in the same directory/package as "DebugExcercise3", then you will need to import it.

At the top of your file, before the class begins, you should have a list of import statements.
Syntax:
import package_name.class_name;
OR
import package_name.*;

If you right click the red line issue where IntelliJ is complaining it should offer quick fixes and usually one of them is to import the class. You must either do this or import it manually.

You can also go to the menu bar > preferences > Actions on Save, and select Optimize imports. This will tell IntelliJ to grab and remove imports you need/do not need every time you hit save.